# Can't change PHP.ini in my own server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php5

I have a Development platform with **magic_quotes_gpc Off**, and I can't turn it Off on my Validation server. Both are Ubuntu 11.04 (thought the Validation server is mount under VMWare). The Dev is uses PHP 5.3.6, the Val uses 5.3.2.

I really **need to turn it Off** on the Validation server. I tried :

- setting it Off on all lines of all php.ini I met
- checked in phpInfo that other /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/*.ini files does not contain magic_quotes config
- tried a php flag and/or php value in .htaccess
- even tried ini_set, thought it does'nt work for this PHP version
- then relaunched the apache server (even using force-reload)

But whatever I try, I still have it **On** in the phpinfo(), and also have **get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1** when I test it inside the code.

In fact, no modifications of php.ini are taken (tried fopen_url and timezone). But if I rename php.ini to php.pouet, phpinfo() says that no configuration files is used. If I rename it again to php.ini, this file is taken.

This is a Business Symfony 2 application, and using stripslashes everywhere is not an option (too slow and dirty). Escaping is well handled by Doctrine.

I just don't understand what's going on !

Answer (score 0):

Search your filesystem for php.ini. On my messy dev server I have normal PHP installation and Zend server. So I had to edit php.ini in Zend server.

And another thing - restart httpd after you change php.ini. In other case configuration will not update.